# How to cut/paste rows from one Excel sheet to 1st blank row of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need any row in Sheet1 that has the word 'Done' in column E to be cut and pasted into the next empty row of Sheet2. My problem is that I don't know how to find the next empty row in Sheet2 and start pasting values to that next empty row.

It's a basic Workbook with two Sheets. Sheet1 has all employee tasks and Sheet2 only displays the tasks that are 'Done'. Anytime an employee finishes a task and types 'Done' in a cell within Column E of Sheet1, that entire row needs to be cut and pasted into the next empty row of Sheet2. I created an ActiveX Command button in Sheet1 with the following code. The code finds any cell in Sheet1 that says 'Done' and cuts/pastes it in Sheet2, but it always starts pasting from the beginning of Sheet2, and I need it to start pasting from the next empty row of Sheet2.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("E1:E1000")   ' Do 1000 rows
    If c = "Done" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Cut Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

My problem is that it keeps overwriting anything that's already in Sheet2 because I don't know what to replace that 'j' variable code with. I need it to find the next empty row in Sheet2 and start pasting from there.

Comment: you can use `Workhseet_Change` event to trigger the cut/paste automatically. Lookup how to find last used row in Excel vba. You'll get plenty of results that can help.

Comment: yes, but my problem is that i need it to paste into the next EMPTY ROW of Sheet2. that's the main problem I'm having and which I need help with, because I can't have the script erase any of the previously completed tasks in Sheet2....it needs to add onto Sheet2, not overwrite anything.

Comment: i repeat -  **Lookup how to find last used row in Excel vba. You'll get plenty of results that can help** - this type of question has been asked many many times on SO.

Comment: You are saying that you have "Done" in column G, however checking column E... which is it ?

Comment: `Range.End`, `Range.Offset`, `Worksheet.UsedRange` and `For` loops are all different possibilities on how to go about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

Dim lRowSrc As Long, lRowDst As Long, lColSrc As Long, R As Long

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

With Source
    lRowSrc = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    lColSrc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For R = lRowSrc To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(R, 5) = "Done" Then
            lRowDst = Target.Cells(Target.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

            Target.Range(Target.Cells(lRowDst + 1, 1), Target.Cells(lRowDst + 1, lColSrc)).Value = .Range(.Cells(R, 1), .Cells(R, lColSrc)).Value
            .Cells(R, 5).EntireRow.Delete   'get rid of the row
        End If
    Next R
End With

End Sub
```

Keep in mind that with a large data set, this aproach is not ideal, and using arrays is much much better. If however you only have a small number of rows (assume so...), it should be fine.

**EDIT:** used last row variable instead of the current row for copying values. Fixed.

Comment: Yes, I do only have a small number of rows. Say it's 20 rows that it needs to search through in Sheet1. It needs to cut ALL of the rows that contain the word 'Done' in column E and paste them in the next available rows of Sheet2. So if rows 3, 6 and 12 of Sheet1 have 'Done' in column E, those 3 rows need to be cut and pasted into the next 3 available rows in Sheet2. It doesn't seem like your code does that exactly. It appears to find the correct rows in Sheet1, but they are not all pasted in Sheet2...only 1 row seems to get pasted at a time. Any idea why?

Comment: Ah... I did an error in the values to be copied... see updated code in a second.